# Is there a bug in scikits ARI implementation or is my understanding of the algorithm flawed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, scikits

When calculating the [ARI](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#adjusted-rand-score) with [scikit's implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html), I noticed a weird case. For certain lists that look as if there were high consensus in the labeling, the ARI is still 0.0 or even worse.

I have tried several labelings, the follwing being the weirdest one to observe:

```
from sklearn import metrics as m

labels_true = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
labels_pred = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]

res = m.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true,labels_pred)

>>> res = 0.0
```

The result of that is 0.0, which is an indicator of the two lists being completely random labelings. Looking at them, intuitively one would say it is a pretty good labeling, except for one list entry, which is a label to class 0 instead of class 1. This is even a realistic clustering result, for example if there is only one cluster in a small data set without noise and one point is classified wrong (class 0) by mistake.

My question is: is my understanding of 'good' labelings completely wrong, or is there maybe some sort of bug or even undocumented input restrictions for the algorithm?

Comment: I can verify the behavior on my system, and have opened a bug report on [sklearn's GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12940). I think it's a bug. We'll see what they say.

Comment: Also, I verified with sklearn 0.19.1. Not sure what version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue. I think there might be some sort of bug for the case of only one label being present in one of the lists. If you add a 2 to the end of both lists, you magically get an ARI of about 0.633. I am using version 0.20.1

Comment: If I calcuclate the RI (no adjustment) of above example by hand as given by [the wiki def](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index), I get 0.90909090. **But** if i calculate the Numerator of the ARI formula using the contingency table, it is in fact zero. I would even claim that it is always 0 as long as one labeling consists of only one class. If that claim is true, it would mean that ARI as defined in the formula is simply useless for experiments with only one class and no noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and yes.

No: the implementation seems to be correct, and yes: your understanding flawed.

The *adjusted* rand index compares the given result to any random permutation of the labels. **A result is only good if it is better than random.**

Now if you look at the dates any random permutation will be exactly as good. Thus the correct adjusted value is 0: exactly as good as a random permutation.

I do however agree with your assessment that the ARI cannot be used with a one-class problem. Because on such data, all permutations are equal. Wrong tool for your problem: it's about comparing a partitioning of the data set, and you don't have partitioned data...

Comment: The only wording I silghtly disagree with is the last sentence; I might not have partitioning in the ground-truth data, but most algorithms will make small mistakes and leave me with a slightly partitioned result. Since ARI is a symmetric measure, that would be equivalent to having slightly partitioned ground truth data (low noise) and a clustering result of only one class (for whatever reason) - which is the thing that confused me the most.  I just need an algorithm suitable for the one-class problem. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: Maybe NMI works better in that case; but the adjusted version AMI might have the same problem. Adjustment for chance means that you need to define some notion of "expected random result". If you have nothing but the labels, permutations are a popular choice. In particular as permuting one is the same as the inverse permutation of the other, so it is symmetric.

Comment: I can confirm that AMI simply faces the exact same problem!